# handleMessage not being called from ContentObserver

Tags: java, android, service, handler, observable

I am not sure if I understand this correctly, I registered a handler on a observer inside a service. the onChange() for the observer gets triggered on notifyChange() of the contentprovider, but the handler registered to the observer doesnt call handleMessage? Is this something I have todo manually? Am i using an incorrect thread? will post my code below, any feedback would be appreciated, thanx!

```
//Service
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int i, int i1) {

    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand");

    if (mObserver == null) {

        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("Test Thread name", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();
        Looper serviceLooper = thread.getLooper();

        mObserver = new MyObserver(new OurHandler(serviceLooper));
        getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(CustomContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, true, mObserver);
    }

    return 0;
}


 //Handler
  public class OurHandler extends Handler {
    public OurHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        Log.i(TAG, "handleMessage");
    }
}


//onCreate in MainActivity
       Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundService.class);
    startService(i);
```

Comment: *Is this something I have todo manually?* yes, but not directly ... HandlerThread is message queue which would be runned on this thread ...

Comment: Hi, thanx for the reply, ok but can i ask then, what is the point of registering a handler, why cant i just pass in a null? (or should i start a different post)

Comment: you need to call `Handler.sendMessage` (from any thread) Looper will pick the message from queue and then run it(call handleMessage) on HandleThread

Comment: ok cool thank you, I think i understand a bit better now

Comment: post your `MyObserver` class, actually you dont need to create any custom `Handler` (`OurHandler` in your case) - just pass `new Handler(serviceLooper)` - this is API error: `registerContentObserver` should take `Looper` and not `Handler` as a parameter

Comment: @user2042227 my previous comments are more about what is HandlerThread in general but as psink point out has nothing to do with ContentObserver